# javascript: match string to array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a set of values (groups) in a comma delimited string and would like to check if any of those values match any array items (reqRights) and return true or false, but is returns undefined error.

```js
const reqRights = ["18900253","3217840","1053"]; 
const groups    = "3217635,18272308,1053,3217633,18900253,3217698,3217699,3217840,10162510";

function checker(value) {
  var groups = groups.split(",");
  console.log(groups);
  return groups.every(function(v) {
    return value.indexOf(v) !== -1;
  });
}

arr = reqRights.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

**js engine SpiderMonkey 1.8, does not support .includes and some methods**

Comment: just a side not: Doing `groups.split(",");` every single index just makes your loop so much slower. Do it outside so you are not constantly splitting the string up.

Comment: `var groups = groups.split` You can not reuse the same variable. That is your error. Rename one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `const` on `groups`, so you cannot reassign it. And you also should move `groups.split(",")` outside of `checker` function to avoid creating a new array every time calling `checker`.

`some` can help you to check `regRights` item is in `groups` instead of `every`.

```js
const reqRights = ["18900253","3217840","1053"]; 
const groups = "3217635,18272308,1053,3217633,18900253,3217698,3217699,3217840,10162510";

const groupsArray = groups.split(",");

function checkGroupValue(group) { 
   return group === value;
}

function checker(value) {
  return groupsArray.some(checkGroupValue);
}

arr = reqRights.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, i think the js engine running on my webapp doesnt support `some` method  ( line 281: syntax error (line='const even = (element) => element % 2 === 0;
' token='> element % 2 === 0;
').
)

Comment: @DavidGarcia hmm your code in your comment is not in the question, I'm not sure where that error is from. By the way, I just modify my answer to use `function` explicitly. Hopefully, it can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

```
const reqRights = ["18900253","3217840","1053"]; 
const groupsConstant    = "3217635,18272308,1053,3217633,18900253,3217698,3217699,3217840,10162510";

function checker(value) {
  var groups = groupsConstant.split(",");
  return groups.every(v => groups.indexOf(v) !== -1);
}

arr = reqRights.filter(checker);
console.log('elements matched: ', arr.length ? 'yes' : 'no');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to avoid the indexOf as it might give a false positive result (example: reqRight "1053" would be listed if found in "1053568")
THis is not necessarily the shortest way, but should be compatible with spiderMonkey 1.8

```js
const reqRights = ["18900253","3217840","1053"]; 
const groups    = "3217635,18272308,1053,3217633,18900253,3217698,3217699,3217840,10162510";

function checker(values, required) {
  var valuesArray = values.split(",");
  return valuesArray.filter((value) => {
    return required.filter((req) => {
      return req === value; 
    }).length > 0;
  })
}

arr = checker(groups, reqRights);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.find` in filtering from `groups`:

```js
const reqRights = ["18900253","3217840","1053"]; 
const groups    = "3217635,18272308,1053,3217633,18900253,3217698,3217699,3217840,10162510";
const checker = value => 
 ({[value]: reqRights.find(v => value === v) ? true : false});
const checked = groups.split(`,`).map(checker);
console.log(checked);
```

Or maybe concat both (`groups` as array) arrays, sort that numerically and filter the result on double values.

```js
const reqRights = ["18900253","3217840","1053"]; 
const groups    = "3217635,18272308,1053,3217633,18900253,3217698,3217699,3217840,10162510";
const checked = groups.split(`,`)
  .concat(reqRights)
  .sort( (a, b) => +a - +b)
  .filter((v, i, self) => self[i+1] === v);
  
console.log(checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const reqRights = ["18900253","3217840","1053"]; 
const groups    = "3217635,18272308,1053,3217633,18900253,3217698,3217699,3217840,10162510";

const res = groups.split(',').map(item => {
    return reqRights.some(n => item === n)
});

console.log(res);
```